# Error trying to install python package Box2D

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install version 2.3.10 of package Box2D via pip. However pip returns the following error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Box2D==2.3.10 (from versions: 2.0.2b1, 2.3b0, 2.3.2)
```

It looks as though pip does not know about the existence of any version more recent than 2.3.2. However, from this [link](https://pypi.org/project/Box2D/#history) it seems clear that it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Box2D 2.3.10 [provides](https://pypi.org/project/Box2D/2.3.10/#files) wheels for Python 2.7 and 3.5 up to 3.8. No wheels for 3.9 or 3.10 and no source code.

Version 2.3.2 [has only source code](https://pypi.org/project/Box2D/2.3.2/#files).

So either you use version 2.3.2 or downgrade to Python 3.8 or install using [conda](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d#how-to-get-it) or install from Github:

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d.git@2.3.10#egg=Box2D-2.3.10"
```

Or install from [Github release](https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/releases/tag/2.3.10):

```
pip install https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d/archive/refs/tags/2.3.10.tar.gz
```

*Upd* It also requires [swig](/questions/tagged/swig) so I tried

```
sudo apt install swig &&
pip install "git+https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d.git@2.3.10#egg=Box2D"
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: pip install "git+https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d.git@2.3.10#egg=Box2D-2.3.10"
still returns 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement box2d-2-3-10 (unavailable) (from versions: none)

Comment: @noesis It also requires [tag:swig] so I tried: `sudo apt install swig && pip install "git+https://github.com/pybox2d/pybox2d.git@2.3.10#egg=Box2D"` and it worked for me.

Comment: Ok, it seemed to work but now it doesn't. Tried to run conda install box2d but it doesn't find the package. Any idea?

Comment: Try `conda install pybox2d` or `conda install -c conda-forge pybox2d`

Comment: for mac users ending up here, `brew install swig` is an option.